# Why does my reloaded model produce a different prediction?

Tags: keras

```
#train model

#here is one sample
sample = validation_X[0].reshape(1, -1)

#print the sample for reference
print(sample)

#show the weights for reference
print(model.get_weights())

#show prediction
print(model.predict(sample))

#another prediction that is the same as above
print(model.predict(sample))

#save model
model.save('mymodel.h5')

#reload model
model = load_model('mymodel.h5')

#sample looks to be the same as above
print(sample)

#weights also look to be the same as above
print(model.get_weights())

#prediction is different here?
print(model.predict(sample))
```

Why is my model predicting a different value after reloading it? I check and the sample is obviously the same, and from an eye test the weights look to be the same too. What could be causing the model to product a different prediction here?

Answer (score 0):

If the models are loaded in two different instances, then you must always save the model weights and reload them. The model weights may look similar due to small real numbers, but you need to save and reload the weights so that the learned weights are the same.